# Postgres Query Using Join Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables:

`users`, `public_pictures`, `pictures`

Import properties:

`users.id`

`public_pictures.user_id`

`public_pictures.picture_id`

`pictures.id`

`public_pictures` is a join table between `users` and `pictures` with only those two properties above. Both are foreign keys to their respective table.

Given a `user.id`, I want to get all their public pictures. I tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM pictures
INNER JOIN public_pictures
ON pictures.user_id = '1';
```

but this just returns all the user's images instead of only the public ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables with their joining columns and as far as i can see only public_pictures has a user_id.

so the query must look like

```
SELECT * FROM pictures pi
INNER JOIN public_pictures pp
ON pp.picture_id = pi.id
WHERE pp.user_id = '1';
```